# Object is invalid as react child while trying to use async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to add translation system in my app. My sample code:

```
async translate(txt){
 var res = await translate(txt, {
   //some props
 })

 return res[0] //it was returned as an object, so taking the first element
}

render(){
 return (
   <View>
    <Text>{this.translate('Hello')}</Text>
   </View>
 )
}
```

I know, async returns a promise but I could not figure out a way to use it in my case.

I have checked other questions, but those didn't work :(

Comment: <Text>{() => this.translate('Hello')}</Text>

Comment: @Arthur it shows nothing, blank

Answer (score 1):

You would need to wait for the promise to resolve before displaying the output of `translate` so you could use a state to store the output once `translate` finishes.

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.translate("Hello").then((output) => this.setState({ text: output }));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{this.state.text ? this.state.text : "Loading"}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: as i said, it is to show auto translation. using a huge state won't make sense here